# Elasticsearch + Kibana, no logstash, web issue

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a AWS instance, set up a log aggregator. I would like to setup Kibana and Elasticsearch there. Kibana went up and configured itself, but it doesn't connect to Elasticsearch, which is running on the same machine. The error in `/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log` says:

```
"Kibana: Unable to create Kibana index ".kibana"
Error: IndexCreationException[[.kibana] failed to create index]; nested: NoClassDefFoundError[Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.PostingFormats]; 
at respond (http://52.16.186.218/index.js?_b=5930:81566:15)
at checkRespForFailure (...)
at wrappedErrback (...)
at wrappedErrback (...)
at wrappedErrback (...)
at Scope.$eval (...)
at Scope.$digest (...)
at Scope.$apply (...)
```

Comment: Is everything running the same elasticsearch version (plugins, kibana, etc)?

Comment: KIbana is 4.0.1. elasticsearch is 1.4.4. I found that they are compatibile.